# MVC3, Razor, Html.TextAreaFor(): adjust height to fit contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm currently using the following code in the View to adjust the height of a Html.TextAreaFor() to fit its contents. Is there a significantly better &/or less verbose way to do this?

```
...
int width = 85;
int lines = 1;
string[] arr = Model.Text.Split(new string[] {"\r\n", "\n", "\r"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (var str in arr)
{
    if (str.Length / width > 0)
    {
        lines += str.Length / width + (str.Length % width <= width/2 ? 1 : 0);
    }
    else
    {
        lines++;
    }
}
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Text,
                  new
                  {
                      id = "text",
                      style = "width:" + width + "em; height:" + lines + "em;"
                  })

...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks fine. One possible improvement would be to externalize it into a reusable helper to avoid polluting the view:

```
public static class TextAreaExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString TextAreaAutoSizeFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var model = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model;
        var text = model as string ?? string.Empty;
        int width = 85;
        int lines = 1;
        string[] arr = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (var str in arr)
        {
            if (str.Length / width > 0)
            {
                lines += str.Length / width + (str.Length % width <= width / 2 ? 1 : 0);
            }
            else
            {
                lines++;
            }
        }
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        attributes["style"] = string.Format("width:{0}em; height:{1}em;", width, lines);
        return htmlHelper.TextAreaFor(expression, attributes);
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.TextAreaAutoSizeFor(m => m.Text, new { id = "text" })
```

Comment: Reusable, makes maintenance easier, and unclutters the view... and works like a charm! Just had to add the using directives: using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

Answer (score 3):

That looks great,
you can also use the [JQuery autogrow textarea plugin](http://www.technoreply.com/autogrow-textarea-plugin/).

It will save you some coding, and may even be more efficient.

Comment: Great plugin. Torn between this answer and Darin Dimitrov's! Might be a wee bit fancier than I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce this to one line with some LINQ magic:

```
var lines = Model.Text.Split( new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None )
  .Aggregate( 0, (total, next) => 
    total += next.Length <= width ? 1 
      : (int)Math.Ceiling( (double)next.Length / width ) );
```

Note that there's a wee problem with the way you're splitting.  If there really are mixed `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n` line endings in your input (unlikely), this split will split in order from left to right, so it won't ever split on the string `\r\n`, which will mean an empty line between the `\r` and the `\n`.  So you'll see I moved the `\r\n` as the first string in the split.

Comment: Right you are; I corrected this problem in the answer.  Good catch!

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Compact and works! Used it in conjunction with Darin's answer.